# I'm having trouble trying to calculate the sum and average involving an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sum, average

I am trying to calculate the sum and average of certain values such as:

The list of values:
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0

Then after I enter my sentinel value of -1.0 it calculates the average which would be 2.5. However, I am ending up with a long negative number (-9255963134931...). I am new to arrays and am confused as how to get my desired output. Any help is appreciated.
(How would one also find the middle value with an if else statement?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, count=0;
    double scores [10];
    double value;
    double sum=0.0;

    cout << "Author: J. Soto\n";

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    cout<<"Input -1.0 when you are ready to stop."<<endl;
    cout<<"Input a value: ";

    cin>>value;

    while(value!= -1.0 && count<10) {
        scores [count] = value;
        count = count + 1;

        cout<<"Input a value: ";
        cin>> value;

    }

    cout<<"\nYou entered "<<count<<" values"<<endl;


    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        cout << setw(6) << scores[i];
        sum= value+scores[count];
        cout << "\n\nThe average of the values is:" << sum << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should get used to declaring variables right before first usage and keep them in a most inner scope.

Answer (score 3):

`scores[count]` will be a garbage value, since `count` is 10 by that point.

I think what you want is

```
sum += scores[i];
```

and the average will then be (after the loop ends)

```
sum / count
```

Comment: Well, count may not be 10, but whatever it is there is garbage in scores[count]

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. Another question, how would one go about finding the middle value in an array with an if else statement?

Comment: First ask yourself why you would even need an if-else statement, that should give you a hint...

Comment: If a value is odd then display one middle element? Else, display two middle elements?

Comment: Good job! Not the value, the count but yes. So how do you get the middle element if count is odd?

Comment: That I'm not sure of. I would assume divide?

Comment: Hmm SO doesn't want us to have a long discussion here, and you don't have the rep for chat. Don't worry, keep at it I'm sure you'll figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this in your final loop:

```
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
{ 
    cout<<setw(6)<< scores[i];
    sum += scores[i];
}

cout<<"\n\nThe average of the values is:"<< (sum / count) <<endl;
```

So, you accumulate the `sum` by adding each `score[i]` and at the end, you divide the `sum` by `count` to give the average.

Answer (score 1):

I believe sum/count will fit better what you're intending to do.

Try adding

```
cout<<"\n\nThe average of the values is:"<< (sum / count) <<endl;
```

after the for loop, so the average value will be calculated properly and only one time.